# File based storage vs Block based storage?

Tags: filesystems, nas, san, block-storage

After reading about File vs. Block storage at [File vs. Block storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3r9RGJ0_Bls) on 18.15m , looks like both both block based storages(SAN) and files
based storage devices(NAS) stores the internally as block .

But at couple of other resources like https://stonefly.com/resources/what-is-file-level-storage-vs-block-level-storage and https://www.networkworld.com/article/3256312/what-is-a-san-and-how-does-it-differ-from-nas.html I see below claim

> A SAN stores data at the block level, while NAS accesses data as
>   files.
>
> It stores files and folders and the visibility is the same to the
>   clients accessing and to the system which stores it.

From this looks like File based storages stores the data as file(not blocks) in sequential fashion. Not sure which one is true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of terminology only. On their back-ends, both types of systems store data in blocks and the difference between them is in front-end protocols they provide to a client. Block storage systems allow access via block-level protocol - in the most cases it's SCSI (SCSI over FC or SCSI over TCP/IP - iSCSI). Respectively, front-end of a file storage operates on file-level protocols: NFS, SMB/CIFS. It happens, a storage device can work in both modes: block and file.

Comment: Ok. But if file storage system also stores the data in block, why it is said to be sequential read/write ? Is it because file storage generally read  the data from contiguous blocks whereas block storage read the data from random blocks ?

Comment: @user3198603, You can't predict how and on what order blocks are written on one or another storage system. It's highly dependent of technologies used by a vendor to distribute data over drives. It's not even as simple as RAID levels, because it can be accumulated for optimisation in cache before it's written to drives. Also, nowadays, the most of the storage systems use variations of thin-provisioning over virtual RAID-groups and automatic tiering between slow/normal/fast drives. And of course, both NAS and SAN support random as well as sequential operations.